# WCF Service hosted in a Console Application

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, console-application, self-hosting

How much load can a WCF service, hosted in a console application handle? Can it handle incoming requests as much as a WCF hosted on IIS?

Additional Notes:
Can requests arrive concurrently?

I have a WCF service hosted in a console app. I call this WCF service from within a web app. That web app may have hundreds of requests concurrently.

I have simulated a load of requests but I couldn't find out if the console app which hosts the WCF service is actually answering them concurrently or sequentially.

Comment: You can load test services using something like loadui. You can also configure a wcf to handle requests concurrently. A quick google should get you on your way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the WCF service is hosted. It all depends on the binding, endpoint,  endpoint behavior and service behavior settings and, last but not least, on the way you set (via attributes) the instancing mode and concurrency type for your service.

These settings are taken over by the [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) instance. Even if it's running in a console app, the application itself is just a container for the `ServiceHost` which is the one that creates the runtime environment for your WCF service, based on the settings you give it.

For what interests you, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (concurrency and throttling). Also, something very [extensive on WCF instance modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx).

For performance reasons I recommend you use a singleton service, which you can specify via the InstanceContextMode. If you have hundreds of requests coming in, it won't do any good to concurrency if a service instance is created for each request. You have to analyze if singleton is possible in your case by checking if all your service operations are thread safe.

Comment: It seems singleton is not possible in my case because a lot of applications will make a lot of requests/minute.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian: Doesn't really matter how many requests there are. Could be thousands/sec. As long as you don't keep any state or some kind of custom session in your services (such as static collections with some data altered and read by all requests), you're OK.

Answer (score 1):

> How much load can a WCF service, hosted in a console application handle?

As much as your computer can for self-hosted WCF service.

The host can be a console app or windows service, doesn't matter, from load perspective they are the same.